# Calculations involving multiple radio buttons in two group boxes in C#

Tags: c#, radio-button

Hello I'm a little stuck on a task involving radio buttons. I am using an else... if statement to determine which radio boxes are checked and I then want a different calculation to be done depending on what radio button is selected from both of the group boxes. In one group box I have 3 options which are items of clothing and the price and in the other group box I have 4 options which are quantities 1-4. When two radio buttons are selected (one from each group box) I would like a calculation to take place. I think my if statements are correct but i'm having trouble doing the calculation and converting it to string as i've only ever done calculations using txtboxes which i then convert to int or double and involve them in the calculation. since I'm not using a textbox on this form i'm stumped here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Radio_Button_task
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    bool blnChecked = true;

    private void btnEnd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispose();
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblTotal.Text = "";
        rbtnJeans.Checked = false;
        rbtnQuant1.Checked = false;
        rbtnQuant2.Checked = false;
        rbtnQuant3.Checked = false;
        rbtnQuant4.Checked = false;
        rbtnShirt.Checked = false;
        rbtnShorts.Checked = false;
    }

    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double dbTotal;
        if (rbtnJeans.Checked && rbtnQuant1.Checked)
        {
            dbTotal = Convert.ToDouble(28 * 1);
        }
        else if (rbtnJeans.Checked && rbtnQuant2.Checked)
        {
            dbTotal = Convert.ToDouble(28 * 2);
        }
        else if (rbtnJeans.Checked && rbtnQuant3.Checked)
        {
            dbTotal = Convert.ToDouble(28 * 3);
        }
        else if (rbtnJeans.Checked && rbtnQuant4.Checked)
        {
            dbTotal = Convert.ToDouble(28 * 4);
        }
        lblTotal.Text = "The total cost is: £" + dbTotal.ToString("0.00");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: my error is that "dbtotal" is unassigned =S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not handling the case where no radio buttons or only one is checked.  Initialize dbTotal to zero.

Comment: thankyou it runs now and works =] I had a feeling It would be a tiny little thing that would be wrong it was the same when I was trying to switch between two images i put picNum2 instead of picNum1 =/ Still quite new at this but really enjoying it thankyou for your help you saved my laptop from going out the window =]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is all of those if statements could all be false. If that happened, you'd use `dbTotal` at the very end without assigning anything to it. The compiler does not like that.

The simple fix is to just initialize `dbTotal` when you create it:

```
double dbTotal = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Same thing can be done like this. Run a similar loop for Items selection also. Here "gbQuan" is the Groupbox/Panel which has all the Radiobuttons.

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
double quan = 0, item = 28;
foreach (RadioButton temp in gbQuan.Controls)
{
    if (temp.Checked)
        quan = Convert.ToDouble(temp.Text);
}
lblTotal.Text = "The total cost is: £" + (item * quan).ToString("0.00");
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've dabbled with loops by building a times table program and I'd love to put it in to show off but its not what she asked for and last time i went "beyond the call of duty" she told me to take it out =/ The stuff i'm doing now is the task she will be showing us next lesson but I can't help but do it before I get there as I love programming and have only been doing it for 4 weeks =P Thankyou though I could always do it in a different program so she wont tell me to take it out =]